# Swiftui : Firebase array retrieving

Tags: ios, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui

I am retrieving all my data but all paragraphs are in last subject(node 0 is a subject see picture). I mean every subject have his own list of paragraphs but it seems like paragraphs are being iterated too. How to avoid nested data from iterating because **videos** and **images** are in the same case
[image: Firebase screen]

Here is my code

```
func getSubjects() {
     self.database.child("subjects").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for subject in snapshot.children{
            let childSnap = subject as! DataSnapshot
            let value = childSnap.value as? NSDictionary
            //print(snapshot.value!)
            let title = value?["title"] as? String ?? ""
            let text = value?["text"] as? String ?? ""
            let place = value?["place"] as? String ?? ""
            let img = value?["img"] as? String ?? ""
            let video = value?["video"] as? String ?? ""
            
            let location = value?["location"] as? NSDictionary
            let latitude = location?["latitude"] as? String ?? ""
            let longitude = location?["longitude"] as? String ?? ""
            let name = location?["name"] as? String ?? ""
            let loc = Location(name: name, latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)               

            let paragraphs = childSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "paragraphs")
            for par in paragraphs.children{
                let para = par as! DataSnapshot
                let dict = para.value as! [String: Any]
                let locationPara = dict["location"] as? NSDictionary
                let latitudePara = locationPara?["latitude"] as? String ?? ""
                let longitudePara = locationPara?["longitude"] as? String ?? ""
                let namePara = locationPara?["name"] as? String ?? ""
                let titlePara = dict["title"] as? String ?? ""
                let textPara = dict["text"] as? String ?? ""
                let teaching = dict["teaching"] as? String ?? ""
                
                let images = para.childSnapshot(forPath: "img")
                for image in images.children{
                    let photoSnap = image as! DataSnapshot
                    let photo = photoSnap.value as! [String: Any]
                    let descImg = photo["description"] as? String ?? ""
                    let linkImg = photo["link"] as? String ?? ""
                    let titleImg = photo["title"] as? String ?? ""
                    let imgPara = Media(description: descImg, title: titleImg, link: linkImg)
                    self.imgList.append(imgPara)
                }
                let videos = para.childSnapshot(forPath: "video")
                for video in videos.children{
                    let vidSnap = video as! DataSnapshot
                    let vid = vidSnap.value as! [String: Any]
                    let descVid = vid["description"] as? String ?? ""
                    let linkVid = vid["link"] as? String ?? ""
                    let titleVid = vid["title"] as? String ?? ""
                    let videoPara = Media(description: descVid, title: titleVid, link: linkVid)
                    self.vidList.append(videoPara)
                }
                
                let locPara = Location(name: namePara, latitude: latitudePara, longitude: longitudePara)
              
                self.mapList.append(locPara)
             
                let paragraph = Paragraph(title: titlePara, text: textPara, teaching: teaching, images: self.imgList, videos: self.vidList, location: locPara)
                self.paragraphList.append(paragraph)
            }
             
            let subject = Subject(title: title, text: text, place: place, img: img, video: video, location: loc, paragraphs: self.paragraphList)
            self.subjectList.append(subject)
        
            print("SubjectT :\(title)")
        }
    }){ (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

As you can see there is many array inside a subject

Comment: That's quite some code, and I don't immediately see what the problem is. When you step through this code in a debugger, which lines doesn't do what you expect it to do? It typically helps if you can show that problem as the output of a `print` statement.

Comment: In debugger it's a lot of data. Please look at my comment below.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand, but it sounds like you want to avoid decoding all of the different types of data within Videos and Images when you are fetching your subjects.

From the way your data is setup, that may not be possible. From my understanding, when you attempt to read you must decode everything in that node. Are you trying to access a specific video? Or specific image? If that's the case you can adjust your read be something like:

```
self.database.child("subjects").child("paragraphs").child("images")
```

or

```
self.database.child("subjects").child("paragraphs").child("images")
```

this will limit the read to only the data within those nodes.

Also, it may be helpful to invest some time implementing Codable. If you make your structs Codable, Swift will handle the parsing for you, that way you can simply access the values as opposed to having to map them yourself.

```
struct Subject {
   var title: String
   var paragraphs: [Paragraph]
   // etc for rest of top level items in Subject
}

struct Paragraph {
  var images: [CustomImage] // or whatever you want to call it
  var videos: [Video]
  // etc for rest of vars
}

struct Video {
  var description: String 
  // etc for rest of vars
}
```

You have to make sure variable names match what's in your database, but other than that, Codable does all the work for you. Then, when you read the data, all you have to do is something like:

```
JSONDecoder().decode(Subject.self, from: data)
```

or something like that pending on your read, and it'll save you all that parsing

Comment: Thanks for the answer. All names match with the database. For example if you have a post on your database with its comments you will want to retrieve it with the comments which concern it not those of other posts. Only every second post comes with the comments of the first one and so on suddenly the last post retrieved contains all the comments of the previous posts; and it's not what I want. It's pretty much the same, every subject has its paragraphs and these paragraphs have their images and videos.